# unexpected response 404 on getRequestForSearch

Tags: rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sosl

I am developing a native android app using the mobile sdk.
I am trying to make a search query like this

```
 RestRequest req = RestRequest.getRequestForSearch("v20.0", "Find '"+searchString+"*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Task(Id,Name)");
```

where searchString is something like "Marc"

the problem is that I get

```
 BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected Response Code 400 for https://eu3.salesforce.com/services/v20.0/search? ....
```

Comment: 404 is "Not found" whereas 400 is "Bad request". If its the latter, then the first thing to check is your `searchString`. Best if you make the question title and body consistent.

Comment: Try  demarcating your `searchString` with {}, not with single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using `SOSL` via an API request, not inside Apex. There is a little difference that we need to note down in this case. [Here the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm).

> In Apex, the value of the FIND clause is demarcated with single
>   quotes. 
>  For example: `FIND 'map*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING
>   Account (Id, Name), Contact, Opportunity, Lead` 
>  
>  In the
>   Force.com API, the value of the FIND clause is demarcated with braces.
>   For example:
>  `FIND {map*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account (Id,
>   Name), Contact, Opportunity, Lead`

Your are getting the bad request response due to the single quote mark around the search string. Instead use {}.

```
RestRequest req = RestRequest.getRequestForSearch("v20.0", "Find {"+searchString+"*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Task(Id,Name)");
```

Comment: I have tried it and I still get the same error

Comment: Any special characters in the searchString?